# RoR Controller -Permission for a specific role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck with giving specific roles permissions. I created 8 different roles with an enum. 2 of them should be allowed to create some "cases". How can I implement that? Maybe someone can help me? Is giving permission the right way?

PS: I'm using Rails 6.0.3.4.

Here my code:

**Cases Controller:**

```
    class CasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_case, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cases
  # GET /cases.json
  def index
    @cases = Case.all
  end

  # GET /cases/1
  # GET /cases/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cases/new
  def new
    @case = Case.new
  end

  # GET /cases/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cases
  # POST /cases.json
  def create
    @case = Case.new(case_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @case.save
        format.html { redirect_to @case, notice: 'Case was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @case }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cases/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cases/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @case.update(case_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @case, notice: 'Case was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @case }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cases/1
  # DELETE /cases/1.json
  def destroy
    @case.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cases_url, notice: 'Case was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_case
      @case = Case.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def case_params
      params.require(:case).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :birthdate, :place_of_residence, :diagnosis, :user_id, :confirmed_at)
    end
end
```

**Application Controler:**

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :authenticate_user!

end
```

**User.rb**

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin, :arzt, :labor, :ga, :ls, :rki]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?

   def set_default_role
     self.role ||= :user
   end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: This is rather a lot of code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Next time I'll keep that in mind. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution might be a before action...

```
CasesController << ApplicationController

  before_action :allowed_to_create, only: [:new, :create]

  private

  def allowed_to_create
    unless current_user.role.in?(['type1', 'type2'])
      flash[:error] = 'You are not allowed to do that'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

If your permmissions are likely to be more complex, take a look at the `cancancan` gem.

Comment: Thank you!!! That should be the perfect solution for me. 

The roles 'arzt' and 'labor' should be able to create some cases. So I did it that way:

`class CasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_case, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :allowed_to_create, only: [:new, :create]

  private
  def allowed_to_create
    unless current_user.role.in?(['arzt', 'labor'])
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end`
...

When I'm logged in as 'arzt' oder 'labor' unfortunately I get the following error:

Comment: Argument Error in Cases#new
line #1 raised:
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1):

`<%= form_for @case do |form| %>
  <% if @case.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@case.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this case from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @case.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">`
 
...

Do u know why?

Comment: Um... no, I don't.  You're clearly rendering `new` and in `new` you set `@case = Case.new` so I'm not sure why `@case` in the form is nil.  Just as an experiment, create this line in the form immediately before the `form_for` line... `<% @case ||= Case.new %>` and see what happens...

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)